# How to call bottom sheet?

Tags: forms

Well I have a form look and since I avoided to use dropdowns and in this case I have a category which user has to pick from bottom sheet (I use them to replace dropdowns). Now I don't know how to in this form look to create some kind of component from which BS can be called from. I saw in some cases that people still use dropdown field and activate BS from that but some of the collages disagree with that. Can you offer me some solution for this ? Thanks !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to replace the standard dropdown field with a custom one that uses a bottom sheet instead of a popup.

I agree that that your field shouldn't look like a normal dropdown, because it would betray user's expectation.

In this case, you have a field that opens an overlay/modal when interacted with. You want to indicate this behavior to your users.

1. One solution would be to change the dropdown indicator (arrow icon) with a different one. If you search images for "overlay icon" you will get a bunch of variations.
2. Another solution would be to replace the arrow indicator with an actual word, like "edit", which will suggest to users that the field requires a special editing behavior.
3. Yet another solution would be to attach an action button to the field (on right side) that will open your overlay. See Bootstrap "input group" for inspiration.